# Error when running pip install discord.py

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am on a mac OS with python 3.5.3
I am completely new to python.
This is the command line when I try to run `pip install discord.py`

```py
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7k/_5tkn2z940bfbjwc6jxhdvb40000gp/T/pip-install-HvXx9C/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7k/_5tkn2z940bfbjwc6jxhdvb40000gp/T/pip-install-HvXx9C/aiohttp/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/7k/_5tkn2z940bfbjwc6jxhdvb40000gp/T/pip-pip-egg-info-Zb_d0r
         cwd: /private/var/folders/7k/_5tkn2z940bfbjwc6jxhdvb40000gp/T/pip-install-HvXx9C/aiohttp/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/7k/_5tkn2z940bfbjwc6jxhdvb40000gp/T/pip-install-HvXx9C/aiohttp/setup.py", line 60, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+")
    RuntimeError: aiohttp requires Python 3.4.2+
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It seems you pip version is using python2 and you most probably have multiple python versions installed on your system. Try with `pip3 install discord.py`

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `pip` command is pointing to Python 2. discord.py requires Python 3.4.2 or higher. Try using:

```
pip3 install discord.py
```